# Simple question about iterating 2 arrays in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I'm iterating a NSArray in objective-c with:

```
for (id object in array1) {
  ...
}
```

I now have another array2, and I need to access with the same index of the current array1.

Should I use another for statement ?

thanks

Comment: No, you should not use another **for** statement.  The shared index suggests that (depending on the scopes of the two arrays) a better design might be to have a single combined array, helping enforce a correspondence of objects in both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have several options:

1. Use c-style for loop as Dan suggested
2. Keep track of current index in a separate variable in fast-enumeration approach:

   ```
   int index = 0;
   for (id object in array1) {
      id object2 = [array2 objectAtIndex:index];
      ...
      ++index;
   }
   ```
3. Use `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` method (OS 4.0+):

   ```
   [array1 enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
       id obj2 = [array2 objectAtIndex:idx];
       ...
   }];
   ```

Comment: @Patrick: it's a nice solution and I didn't think of it myself.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to share indexes, you can use a c style for loop:

```
for( int i = 0; i < [array1 count]; ++i )
{
    id object2 = [array2 objectAtIndex:i];
    //Do something with object2
}
```

Comment: you're mixing NSArray and C-array syntax; otherwise, I'd +1.

Comment: You're right, forgot, I've been switching between windows and mac programming so much lately I blur the two

Comment: sorry, now you're trying to assign to an r-value.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it right that time, serves me right for not referencing code before I write it