# Invalid operands to binary expression ('NSMutableArray' and 'double')

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to store double value into Array and later combine to compute some results but I have encounter some error. Is there another way to do it?

```
NSMutableArray *storeImpedance;
NSMutableArray *storeLength;

double designFrequency = 1e9;
double simulateFrequency = 1.5e9;
double pi = 3.14159265359;
double omega = 2*pi*simulateFrequency;
double Z0=50;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    storeImpedance = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:25];
    storeLength = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:25];
}

- (IBAction)addButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    storeCount++;
    [storeImpedance addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[impedanceTextField.text doubleValue]]];
    [storeLength addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[lengthTextField.text doubleValue]]];

}

if (imageIndex==1)
{
      thetarad=storeImpedance*pi/180*simulateFrequency/designFrequency;
      A=cos(thetarad);
      B=I* storeImpedance*sin(thetarad);
      C=I*sin(thetarad)/storeImpedance;
      D=cos(thetarad);
}
```

Comment: `storeImpedance` is an NSMutableArray - why would you think that you could multiply it by a double?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this line:

```
hetarad=storeImpedance*pi/180*simulateFrequency/designFrequency;
```

You are using `storeImpedance` which is of type `NSMutableArray` and the expected type in this expressions is `double`.

Extract the required `double` value from the array and use it to fix the problem:

```
NSNumber *number = (NSNumber *)[storeImpedance firstObject]; // Or use objectAtIndex: for a specific value in the array if it is not the first one
double value = [number doubleValue];

hetarad=value*pi/180*simulateFrequency/designFrequency;
```

If you want to calculate `hetarad` for each value in the array:

```
for (id element in storeImpedance) {
    NSNumber *number = (NSNumber *)element 
    double value = [number doubleValue]; 

    hetarad=value*pi/180*simulateFrequency/designFrequency;
    // You should do something with hetarad here (either store it or use in other required logic otherwise it will be overwritten by the next iteration
}
```

Comment: If I want to use all value in the array how can I do it ?

Comment: If you got 2 array variable elements can I put 2 id in the for loop ?

Comment: nope you will have to loop each array seperately. If the two arrays are of the same size you can use one for loop with an index and extract the value from each array using that index

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966057/simple-question-about-iterating-2-arrays-in-objective-c